# HashMap<HashSet, Long> comparing strings in hashset and dividing them

Tags: java, string, hashmap, hashset

I'm posting the code for the following task. 
I have a hashmap with entries like so:

```
HashMap<HashSet<String>, Long> mapping = new HashMap<>();

aaa.bb.cc.d, aaa.bb.cc, gg.hh.ee, aaa.bb, 34523
fff.kk.mmmm.ft, iiii.pp.cds, fff.kk, aaa.b, 4343
tpks.tt.po.d, tpks.tt.po, tpks.tt, aa.bb, 544670
```

The result after running the code should be the following:

```
1st entry key should go in nesteds_2 : aaa.bb.cc.d, gg.hh.ee 
2nd entry key should go in nesteds_3 : fff.kk.mmm.ft, iiii.pp.cds, aaa.b 
3rd entry key should go in nesteds_2 : tpks.tt.po.d, aa.bb 
etc.
```

The strings in the HashSet are all in descending order by length. Whenever a string contains another one, only the longer one is needed. If any of the strings are contained in another i.e. the strings in the HashSet become less than 4 - they should be removed from the HashSet and stored into the corresponding array. Then the whole entry must be removed from the hashmap.

This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea why and how I can improve it?

```
public class Edit {
    public void edit(HashMap<HashSet<String>, Long> hm){
        List<String> li;
        String _1,_2,_3,_4;
        ArrayList<String> nesteds = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> nesteds_2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> nesteds_3 = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Iterator<Map.Entry<HashSet<String>, Long>> it = hm.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            li = new ArrayList<String>((Collection<? extends String>) it.next().getKey());
            Comparator<String> stringLengthComparator = new Comparator<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2)
                {
                    return Integer.compare(o2.length(), o1.length());
                }
            };

            Collections.sort(li, stringLengthComparator);
            _1 = li.get(0);
            _2 = li.get(1);
            _3 = li.get(2);
            _4 = li.get(3);


            if(_1.contains(_2)){
                li.remove(_2);
                if(_1.contains(_3)){
                    li.remove(_3);
                    if(_1.contains(_4)){
                        li.remove(_4);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(_1.contains(_3) || _2.contains(_3)){
                    li.remove(_3);
                    if(_2.contains(_4) || _2.contains(_4)){
                        li.remove(_4);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(_3.contains(_4) || _1.contains(_4) || _2.contains(_4)){
                        li.remove(_4);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(li.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The strings in the hashset are all in descending order by length."* No, they're not. Objects in HashSets are not in a meaningful order.

Comment: Yes, that's why for each entry I'm putting every hashset in an arraylist and I'm working with the sorted arraylist when checking if one string contains the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perhaps split your code into methods.

for instance, this method will simplify a collection of strings by removing those that are contained in another:

```
    private static List<String> simplify(Iterable<String> elms) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
outer:
        for (String elm: elms) {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < result.size()) {
                String relm = result.get(i);
                if (relm.contains(elm)) {
                    continue outer;
                } else if (elm.contains(relm)) {
                    result.remove(i);
                } else {
                    ++i;
                }
            }
            result.add(elm);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Your loop would become:

```
    for(Map.Entry<HashSet<String>, Long> e: hm.entrySet()) {
        List<String> li = simplify(e.getKey());
        Collections.sort(li, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o2.length(), o1.length());
            }
        });
        System.out.println(li.toString());
    }
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you. I'm still new to this and I tend to make my life very hard with too much code, when it can be written very elegantly as you did. Cheers.